# Is there an updated solution to fix the Integrity check errors for Blazor WebAssembly Standalone PWA dlls getting blocked by some Antivirus (sophos)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm getting the [Blazor wasm dlls blocked by the Sophos AV](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21996) issue.

And I'm trying to follow this section to fix it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-filename-extension-of-dll-files-2

But the documentation doesn't seem to work at all. Or it's not well explained.

Is there an updated solution to fix the Integrity check errors for Blazor WebAssembly Standalone PWA dlls getting blocked by some Antivirus (sophos)?
Some script or configuration that I turn on and it works?

For instance, the documentation does not cover what just happened to me right now.
I tried to publish the project and it outputs:

```
MyProject.BlazorWasmApp -> D:\MyProject\MyProject.BlazorWasmApp\obj\Release\net5.0\browser-wasm\PubTmp\Out\
powershell.exe -command "& { .\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 'D:\MyProject\' 'net5.0'}"
.\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 : File 
D:\MyProject\MyProject.BlazorWasmApp\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file 
D:\MyProject\MyProject.BlazorWasmApp\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 is not digitally signed. You 
cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, 
see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:5
+ & { .\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 'D:\MyProject\' 'net5.0 ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Then, I changed a bit the command. I changed it from:

```
<Target Name="ChangeDLLFileExtensions" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -command &quot;&amp; { .\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 '$(SolutionDir)' '$(TargetFramework)'}&quot;" />
</Target>
```

To:

```
<Target Name="ChangeDLLFileExtensions" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command &quot;&amp; { .\ChangeDLLExtensions.ps1 '$(SolutionDir)' '$(TargetFramework)'}&quot;" />
</Target>
```

To make it Bypass that "unsigned" error.

But then another problem arises. PowerShell says the _bin folder doesn't exist in:

`$filepath\bin\Release\$tfm\wwwroot\_framework\_bin`

And it DOESN'T indeed! The ps1 file from MS documentation is wrong again.

So I change it to:

`dir $filepath\bin\Release\$tfm\wwwroot\_framework | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace ".dll\b",".bin" }`

Then I execute it and it runs! Great, right? No...

I've just realized that it ran in my own machine. The published files continue to have the dlls...

Oh, and there's more: If I just do that and try to publish again, it'll then error:

`rename-item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

because it's trying to rename the .dll to .bin and the old .bin are still there.

The documentation is really poor, not tested, not real life.

I don't know what else to do. This should be simpler, really. It's been 2 years that this issue has been reported and nothing has been done. The documentation is poor. I'm really sad with it. I was using Blazor as a way to present new tech to my colleagues (which are kinda old-school), but this is disappointing.

I'm guessing Microsoft has too many different versions to maintain (wasm, wasm hosted, pwa, server) and each part of the documentation is written for an specific version and the other versions get forgotten.

By the way, mine is Blazor WASM Standalone PWA.

My question really is what the Title says:

Is there an updated solution to fix the Integrity check errors for Blazor WebAssembly Standalone PWA dlls getting blocked by some Antivirus (sophos)?

Comment: Try reaching out to the AV vendor (sophos), perhaps this is a false positive they can fix